# need help with proving unboundedness of a linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $F$ be a linear functional
defined on $X$. Prove that $F$ is unbounded if and only if for each $a \in X$
and each $r > 0$, $\{F(x) : ||x- a|| < r\} = R$.

where $R$ is the set of all real numbers

Comment: Please specify $R$.

Comment: The title must be explicit. Please change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is trivial.

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, try the contrapositive.  Suppose that you have an $a$ and an $r$ such that $F[B(a,r)]\neq \mathbb{R}$ (where $B(a,r)$ is the open ball centered on $a$ with radius $r$).  First prove that the image of the open ball under $F$ must in fact be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and then prove that $\Vert F\Vert$ is well defined and finite.

---

Disclaimer - I'm tired, and it's a long time since I did any functional analysis, so *caveat emptor*.